# My Django redirect function is not working

Tags: python, django

I am developing a webapp and I cannot seem to execute my view that I have used in redirect method. Can someone help me with it ?

Here is my **views.py**

```
@login_required
def view_task_description(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_description = GetTaskDescription(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if task_description.is_valid():
            obj = GetTaskDescription.get_task_description(task_description)
            return redirect('get_task_description', pk=obj[0].pk)
            # return render(request, 'todoapp/task_desc.html', context={'description': obj[0].description})
    return render(request, 'todoapp/select_task_description.html', context={'view_tasks': GetTaskDescription(user=request.user)})


@login_required
def get_task_description(request, pk):
    # print "Reached get task descrition method"
    obj = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'todoapp/task_desc.html', context={'description': obj.description})
```

Here are my **urls**:

```
url(r'^view_task_description', views.view_task_description, name='view_task_description'),
url(r'^view_task_description/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.get_task_description, name="get_task_description"),
```

Here is my **forms.py**:

```
class GetTaskDescription(forms.Form):

    get_tasks = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Task.objects.none(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=True
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(GetTaskDescription, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['get_tasks'].queryset = self.user.task_set.all()

    def get_task_description(self):
        tasks = self.cleaned_data['get_tasks']
        return tasks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `$` to the first regex, otherwise it will match `/view_task_description/5/` as well as `/view_task_description`.

```
url(r'^view_task_description/$', views.view_task_description, name='view_task_description'),
url(r'^view_task_description/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.get_task_description, name="get_task_description"),
```

I've added a trailing slash as well, to match the usual Django style and your other URL pattern.